# Sumar en datagridview mediante checkbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo un **datagridview** con cantidad, una columna de checkbox, precio y total. Y un método **Montosdgv()** que llamo desde el **CellLeave** del datagridview. Mi método es el siguiente:

```
  private void Montosdgv()
    {
        decimal sumValorTotal = 0;
        decimal sumValorTotal0 = 0;
        decimal sumDescuento = 0;

        foreach(DataGridViewRow fila in dgvIngProductos.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(fila.Cells["checkImporte12"].Value) == true)
            {
                int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["CantidadVendida"].Value);
                decimal venta = Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells["Precio1Prod"].Value);

                decimal CantPorPre = cantidad * venta;

                fila.Cells["ValorTotal"].Value = CantPorPre.ToString("N2");
                sumValorTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells["ValorTotal"].Value);
                txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumValorTotal);
            }
            else
            {

                int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["CantidadVendida"].Value);
                decimal venta = Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells["Precio1Prod"].Value);

                decimal CantPorPre = cantidad * venta;

                fila.Cells["ValorTotal"].Value = CantPorPre.ToString("N2");
                sumValorTotal0 += Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells["ValorTotal"].Value);
                txtSubTotal0.Text = Convert.ToString(sumValorTotal0);
            }
        }
```

El cual si el checkbox no esta activado(false), me muestra el valor en el **textboxNoSeleccionado**, pero si lo activo(true) me muestra el valor en el **textboxNoSeleccionado** y aparte en el **textboxSeleccionado**, y deberia de quitarlo del **textboxNoSeleccionado** para que solo se muestre en el **textboxSeleccionado**. 
Edito: Y si agrego otra fila, no me suma. Solo me muestra el ultimo valor.
¿Como evito esto? 
Para añadir, no sale ningún error en ejecución. Y las filas que ingreso las traigo de otro formulario mediante un botón. Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.